# git log coloring for individual decorations with date?

Tags: git, colors, formatting, logging

I am looking to find a git-log syntax that allows me to have different colors for decorations (like git log pretty=oneline), but also shows the date.

Is that possible?

Seems that everyone showing the date switches to git log -pretty=format, thus requiring %d to show decorations, and %d only can be formatted for one color.

Answer (score 0):

This question is 9 years old with no answer, so for anyone still stumbling onto this, it's:

```
%C(auto)%d%C(reset)
```

Answer (score -1):

With -pretty=format you can use %C to specify the color for each element . 
This is an example

```
--pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

Comment: As I said, to show decorations you need to use %d, and you can't drill into that to specify different colors.